# Practical use of Python as Chrome Native Client

Tags: python, google-nativeclient

There is a Python interpreter in naclports (to run as Google Chrome Native Client App).

Are there any examples for bundling the interpreter with a custom Python application and how to integrate this application with a HTML page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter is currently the only python example in naclports.   However, it should be possible to link libpython into any nacl binary, and use it just as you would embed python in any other C/C++ application.   A couple of caveats: you must initialize nacl_io before making any python calls, and as you should not make python calls on the main (PPAPI) thread.

In terms of interacting with the HTML page, as with all NaCl applications this must be done by sending messages back and forth between native and javascript code using PostMessage().  There is no way to directly access the HTML or JavaScript from native code.

Comment: I am thinking of using what is already there: Is there a way to use the interpreter .pexe as it is (ie no modification or recompile) and to modify the embedding html and js code (ie remove hterm) to start a python script (loaded via http)? I would than use stdio on the Python side to communicate with my JavaScript

Comment: I think this should be possible.  Have a look at the naclterm.js file that is part of the interpreter example.  You can pass arguments to python by setting ARG1..ARGN html attributes on the embed tag.  These will be passed as argv to python's main function.  You can then communicate with python via postMessage to and from the embed tag (again see naclterm.js).